# MPU-6050 as a compass not affected by magnet!

Tags: accelerometer

I am using an MPU-6050 as a compass connected to an Arduino Uno and using the AccZ register presumably from the accelerometer. So, first question, is the magnetometer signal processed internally with the magnetometer output to give true angle in relation to horizontal? Secondly, I placed a powerful magnet as close as I could to the chip and the output appeared to be unaffected. This is a perfect result for my application as my design required several magnets more than 7 cm away from the Sensor. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

> So, first question, is the magnetometer signal processed internally with the magnetometer output to give true angle in relation to horizontal?

The [MPU-6050](https://www.invensense.com/products/motion-tracking/6-axis/mpu-6050/) does not have a magnetometer.

> Secondly, I placed a powerful magnet as close as I could to the chip and the output appeared to be unaffected. This is a perfect result for my application as my design required several magnets more than 7 cm away from the Sensor. Any clues?

There's no magnetometer, so on the one hand it's (probably) not going to be affected by magnets, but on the other hand there's nothing to give you a heading fix. Any heading you're getting from the device is based on numeric integration of the gyro outputs. The gyro output is not perfect, so you're going to have drift in the "heading" you get from the sensor output.

Comment: It looks as if the first digit of the MPUs tells you their DoF. The MPU-9050 (or 9250) have the additional Magnetometer.